# Electromagnetism units conversion in Mathematica 10 (possible bug)

Tags: units, conversion

Is this a bug in Mathematica 10? Why can't [I convert `Amps/m` to Gauss](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/hardware/cal/lvps_info/engineering/mag_conv.htm)?

```
B = Quantity["Teslas"]
H = Quantity["Amperes"/"Meters"]
M = Quantity["Amperes"/"Meters"]

UnitConvert[B, "Gausses"]
UnitConvert[H, "Gausses"]
UnitConvert[M, "Gausses"]
```

Then I get the errors:

```
Out[4]= Quantity[10000, "Gausses"]

During evaluation of In[4]:= Quantity::compat: (Amperes)/(Meters) and Gausses are incompatible units >>

Out[5]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[4]:= Quantity::compat: (Amperes)/(Meters) and Gausses are incompatible units >>

Out[6]= $Failed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Teslas"], Quantity["Gausses"]]

UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Amperes"/"Meters"], Quantity["Oersteds"]]

(* 10000 G *)

(* Pi/250 Oe *)
```